# cannot set proxy password in restricted corporate environment even programmatically

Tags: rebol

When I change login/password through User settings, they don't persist. So I set it programmatically

```
proxy: system/schemes/default/proxy

set in proxy 'host xxx.yyy.www.zzz
set in proxy 'port-id xxxx
set in proxy 'user "login"
set in proxy 'pass "password"
set in proxy 'type 'socks
```

It did persist but when testing it with

```
read http://google.com
```

it takes forever.

These settings work with Firefox so why can't rebol works with them ?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can set the set-net function in Rebol2

USAGE:
    SET-NET settings

DESCRIPTION:
     Network setup.  All values after default are optional.  Words OK for server names.
     SET-NET is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
     settings -- [email-addr default-server pop-server proxy-server proxy-port-id proxy-type esmtp-user esmtp-pass] (Type: block)

Answer (score 0):

REBOL support for proxies is patchy.  For instance it does not work with Squid.  So, that's likely the reason why you're having issues.

Comment: Is this issue on tasks priority? This condemn its use in big companies (> 100000 persons): in all of them I've been working they all have such proxies.

Comment: No more development apart from some minor bug fixes are intended for R2.  All work is on R3 now.